# How do I get an arbitrary entity stored in the context with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework. I just need to get an arbitrary entity from the context so I can use reflection to look at its properties. I don't need any specific entity, any arbitrary one will do. My call should look like this:

```
Entity oldEntity = (Entity)_context.Set(newEntity.GetType()).
```

And some method should go after the last . but I don't see any that would work (find is my best bet but I can't use it since I don't know the ID's of any of the entities).

Edit:

I  forgot to mention that the newEntity I am passing in is generated with a CodeDom class, so newEntity will be the same as the entities in the context, but it may have different properties, which is why I have to get an example "old" entity to compare its properties. To clarify this, imagine I have stored a Person entity with the properties:

- First name
- Last name

Then I want to add a new property, let's say Age. The way I'm doing this is by generating a new Person entity class with CodeDom with Age as an additional property. I have updated the entity class on disk, so I can create a new entity with the extra field, however my SQL table isn't updated.

Comment: It won't let me add more to my edit. The rest is here: However, I don't know what has been added. I just have an example new entity, so I need to compare its properties with the properties of an example "old version" entity, which is why I need to get an example old entity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an actual instance of a class to look at its properties.

You can just use [typeof(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) like  `typeof(Entity).GetProperties()`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention something important, see my edit